# PHP to MSSQL Stored Procedure Unwanted Escape to & Symbol

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, escaping, sqlsrv

My php script that calls a Microsoft SQL Stored Procedure escapes the & (ampersand) symbol (in the database I get `&amp;` instead of &). Unfortunately I need the plain symbol (not the html entity or anything else). I have tried to work around it but I couldn't get it. I have used both PDO and SQLSRV methods. Does someone knows anyway around this? Thanks a lot.

SQLSRV:

```
$tsql_callSP = "{call MyStoredProcedure( ?, ?)}";
$values = array( 
                 array($ID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                 array($Email, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
               );   
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql_callSP, $values);
sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
```

PDO:

```
$tsq = "EXECUTE MyStoredProcedure ?,?";

try
{
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare($tsq);

   $stmt->bindParam(1, $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->bindParam(2, $Email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $stmt->execute();   
}
```